# How can be the badge questions number greater than total questions number?

Tags: discussion, bug

I was checking the top users' profiles and when I was on [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet?tab=topactivity) profile I noticed that his `Socratic` badge got `49/100` questions, while the total number of questions he asked is `48`.

[image]

[image]

I tagged this as a `Bug`, however I'm sure this is not a bug. My guess is that maybe he has deleted a question, and the badge questions count didn't get updated in the database.

Comment: Stop stalking Jon.

Comment: @MarounMaroun perhaps OP is his accountant?

Comment: because it is Jon Skeet

Comment: That's a know Jon Skeet facts. Let me explain it to you: If you have 1 reputation and Jon Skeet have 1 reputation. Jon Skeet have more reputation than you. This is the result of the implementation of this fundamental law.